# Avoid rotation transformation for subviews iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have the view controller where the view hierarchy follows like this,

`viewcontroller.view` -> `GLKView` -> `subviews`(`label`,`buttons`...etc)

So, with the above hierarchy if i'm applying the rotation transformation say for example -90 degree on GLKView then all it's `subviews` get rotated which is a default behavior.
so I want it's subviews to not have rotation transformation and to be in it's same position.

is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: do you want to lock your app int he portrait mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your main view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods
{
    return NO;
}
```

But warning, this method are deprecated, in the futur you should use functions like

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

And all methods like that in your childrens subcontrollers / subviews.